# Check if java is installed in client that downloads jnlp

Tags: java, jnlp

I'm new to jnlp and programming in general. I'm trying to do Screen share using jnlp and red5. In the browser when the client clicks a launch button, the jnlp file is downloaded and opened with Web Start.

I want to see if the client doesn't have java installed and then redirect to download java or download automatically. How do I check and redirect the client.

Comment: i think if the jnlp is executed and your app started, that means java is installed, i.e: if your app started then java is installed and no need to check, right?

Comment: @Yazan. yeah..but if it isn't i have to redirect to the download page..